# Weird Wheel spinning in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

i was working on a simple car controller script and a humvee model i downloaded. the script works as its supposed to but the car wheels are out of place and are spinning crazy. i tried searching everywhere but didn't found any solution.[image: here is the image]

here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GroundVehicleController : MonoBehaviour {

    public void GetInput()
    {
        m_horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        m_verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }

    private void Steer()
    {
        m_steeringAngle = maxSteerAngle * m_horizontalInput;
        frontDriverW.steerAngle = m_steeringAngle;
        frontPassengerW.steerAngle = m_steeringAngle;
    }

    private void Accelerate()
    {
        frontDriverW.motorTorque = m_verticalInput * motorForce;
        frontPassengerW.motorTorque = m_verticalInput * motorForce;
    }

    private void UpdateWheelPoses()
    {
        UpdateWheelPose(frontDriverW, frontDriverT);
        UpdateWheelPose(frontPassengerW, frontPassengerT);
        UpdateWheelPose(rearDriverW, rearDriverT);
        UpdateWheelPose(rearPassengerW, rearPassengerT);
    }

    private void UpdateWheelPose(WheelCollider _collider, Transform _transform)
    {
        Vector3 _pos = _transform.position;
        Quaternion _quat = _transform.rotation;

        _collider.GetWorldPose(out _pos, out _quat);

        _transform.position = _pos;
        _transform.rotation = _quat;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GetInput();
        Steer();
        Accelerate();
        UpdateWheelPoses();
    }

    private float m_horizontalInput;
    private float m_verticalInput;
    private float m_steeringAngle;

    public WheelCollider frontDriverW, frontPassengerW;
    public WheelCollider rearDriverW, rearPassengerW;
    public Transform frontDriverT, frontPassengerT;
    public Transform rearDriverT, rearPassengerT;
    public float maxSteerAngle = 30;
    public float motorForce = 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error on Unity console is telling you the problem:

> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable frontDriverW of
> groundVehicleController has not been assigned. You problably need to
> assign the frontDriverW variable of the GroundVehicleController script
> in the inspector.

Well, when your script runs, it tries to access the field frontDriverW, but since it was never assigned a value, it throws the mentioned exception.

You need to go in the inspector for the object that contains the GroundVehicleController script and add a value for the frontDriverW field. While you're there, make sure all the other fields have values too, because if they don't, those will also cause the same error.

From the pictures you've show us, it is not possible to know in which object you added the GroundVehicleController script, but just check all of the Humvee objects until you find it in the inspector. My guess is that it will probably be in the object Wheels, or the object Humvee.

Comment: i tried many scripts but the issue is still the same.

Comment: @loopiedoopie111 Did you find which Unity Object has the GroundVehicleController script in it, and did you add values to the frontDriverW and other fields for them in the inspector? Did the error continue happening even after you added values to the fields in the inspector?

Answer (score 0):

a) Check the prefab you've created to see if these offsets are there even on the prefab.

b) You're updating the wheel pose with global positions and rotations. this is probably what is causing the offsets. try setting the pose local, or just make the wheel meshes follow whatever the wheel colliders are doing, make sure they're all under the same co-ordinate space. Why not just child each individual wheel to it's corresponding wheel collider? theyre just meshes after all.

c) You haven't assigned your wheel meshes at all in your script.

c) play around with different mass values on the RigidBody (keep it heavy), and also consider attaching a physic material to your wheel colliders to reduce slip and spinning (If the car controller already doesnt have a slip setting)

Comment: can you please provide some code for the second option? setting the pose local.